# How to use anti join on two similar tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

tableA

```
ID      

001
002
003
004
```

tableB

```
ID

002
003
004
005
```

All I want to do is write a SQL statement that grabs all the accounts that are only in tableA.  In this case it would only return

```
ID
001
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which DBMS? See if `except` is available in your DBMS. `select id from tableA except select id from tableB`

Comment: so its actually a PROC SQL statement in SAS so I'm not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, some of them are displayed in following examples. Note that database you use might, or might not support some of them. Also, some might perform better than others (if you deal with large data sets).

`minus` set operator:

```
SQL> select id from tablea
  2  minus
  3  select id from tableb;

ID
---
001
```

Similarly, `except` set operator:

```
SQL> select id from tablea
  2  except
  3  select id from tableb;

ID
---
001
```

Query that uses `not exists`:

```
SQL> select id from tablea a
  2  where not exists (select null from tableb b
  3                    where b.id = a.id);

ID
---
001
```

Query that uses `not in`:

```
SQL> select id from tablea
  2  where id not in (select id from tableb);

ID
---
001

SQL>
```

Comment: You can also do left join like this `SELECT TableA.Id FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableB.Id = TableA.Id WHERE TableB.Id IS NULL`

Comment: As I said, I posted some options; more of them certainly exist. Thank you for your comment, @dev!

Comment: Note that `minus`  is Oracle only (?), but `except` is ISO/ANSI SQL.